# Top 1 result select query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sum

I am getting the below error

> "Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1 Sum(picker_sign_out_sheet.lines_on_order) AS LINES,
>   staff.staff_name AS PICKER' at line 1"

I dont know where to start, hoping for some help

```
("SELECT TOP 1 Sum(picker_sign_out_sheet.lines_on_order) AS LINES, staff.staff_name AS PICKER
FROM picker_sign_out_sheet INNER JOIN staff ON picker_sign_out_sheet.staff_name = staff.staff_id
WHERE (((picker_sign_out_sheet.finish_date)=Date()))
GROUP BY staff.staff_name
ORDER BY Sum(picker_sign_out_sheet.lines_on_order) DESC");
```

I am expecting to get 1 result showing which user has the highest sum of lines_on_order.

Any help would be fantastic

Comment: In response to "I don't know where to start..." I suggest breaking the query down into small components and make sure each one returns what you expect, then build slowly from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove top 01 and get all and get $query->row_array();
this returns only one value which is top

Answer (score 0):

`TOP 1` is not MySQL syntax

Correct query would be

```
SELECT Sum(picker_sign_out_sheet.lines_on_order) AS LINES, staff.staff_name AS PICKER
FROM picker_sign_out_sheet INNER JOIN staff ON picker_sign_out_sheet.staff_name = staff.staff_id
WHERE (((picker_sign_out_sheet.finish_date)=Date()))
GROUP BY staff.staff_name
ORDER BY Sum(picker_sign_out_sheet.lines_on_order) DESC
LIMIT 1
```